# Setup Maven Project with 2 Modules - JSF, Spring, Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, maven, module

I'm using Eclipse and want to setup a MAVEN project which contains two modules for frontend and backend with JSF, Spring and Hibernate.

What I know:
- Create a Maven Project (packaging POM) without archetype
- Create Modules and select the Parent Project (Frontend JAR, Backend WAR)

Which archetypes can I use to combine JSF, Spring, Hibernate?
Do I have to use the same archetype for both modules?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you're going to work with Java EE 6, IMHO it would be better to use EJB instead of Spring beans.

Answer (score 0):

maven archetype is only template those prepare projects folder structure, dependency etc. See
[Maven archetype](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html)

So you can create both module like simple module without archetype and self create folder and depency...
If you can use some archetype you can use some of [these](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List)

ex: for main project: appfuse-basic-jsf and Maven create project which use Spring, hibernate and JSF 
  or softeu-archetype-jsf for JFS nodule and spring-osgi-bundle-archetype for Spring